# Find second occurence of newline before a "-"

Tags: python, regex

So some sample texts are this:

```
Greece: Rare
Athens
Patras
------
```

```
Italy: Unique
Milan
------
```

and i want to get the whole text between the second occurence of a newline before the "-" and the "-".

Expected output:

```
Patras
```

```
Milan
```

Is this possible through regex or should i try something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just search for line before the dashes:

```
import re

text="""Greece: Rare
Athens
Patras
------
"""

print(re.search("(.*)\n-+",text).group(1))
```

prints

```
Patras
```

note that `(.*)` group matches the line but not the previous lines thanks to the fact that `.` doesn't match `\n` by default.

Without regex, this can be done by looking at the index of the dashed line, and printing the previous line.

```
lines = text.splitlines()
index = next(i for i,x in enumerate(lines) if x.startswith("-"))
print(lines[index-1])
```

I'd go for the regex solution though.

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution:

```
import re

texts=["""Greece: Rare
Athens
Patras
------
""","""Italy: Unique
Milan
------"""]
for text in texts:
    print(re.search("\n(.*)\n[-]",text).group(1))
```

Output:

```
Patras
Milan
```